# How to add .cls .sty files in MikTex

Tags: miktex, themes, miktex2.9

I have found a template on internet which looks attractive to me. Then, I soon found some `.cls` and `.sty` files have to be installed in MikTex. I know the directory of MikTex is `User/xxx/Appdata/Programs/MikTex 2.9`, but there are lots of files in there like tex, source, doc, etc. Where should I put my `.cls` file from the internet in?

Comment: create a new folder localtexmf (outside miktex folders) and put your files in `localtexmf/tex/latex/`, then go to the miktex console and add localtexmf as a new root.

Comment: And after than not forget to refresh file name data base.

Comment: Yes I worked it out. Thanks a lot